# How to report spam pdf links in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I sometimes find that the PDF linked to a reference in Google Scholar is spam.
For example, it might have the first two pages of the journal article followed by a link to some website (often in a foreign language).

This is a bit annoying given that often users have a choice of clicking on the PDF or going to a more official publication website.

How do you report spam PDFs  of articles linked to references in Google Scholar?

Comment: Would Google Scholar have a FAQ (frequently Asked Questions) which may tell you?

Answer (score 5):

After a little more hunting, it seems that there is a general "contact us" support page where issues can be submitted.

https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general

Presumably, this would be a way of notifying Google Scholar about spam PDFs.